# Accessing data from array within Gatsby Graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql, gatsby

Im getting stumped here. I have a Gatsby site Im setting up with netlify cms. I have my config file set and I can create the pages and widgets from within netlify admin. When I run my graphql query, I can pull the page info, but I cant access the data from the widget.

admin/config.yml

```
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master # Branch to update (optional; defaults to master)

media_folder: "src/images" # Media files will be stored in the repo under static/images/uploads

collections:
  - name: "pages"
    label: "Page"
    folder: "src/markdown-pages"
    create: true
    fields:
      - {label: "Title", name: "title"}
      - {label: "Content", name: "content"}
      - {label: "Slug", name: "slug"}
      - {label: "Path", name: "path"}
      - label: "Page Sections"
        name: "sections"
        widget: "list"
        types:
          - label: "Call To Action"
            name: "calltoaction"
            widget: object
            fields:
              - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Content", name: "content", widget: "markdown", required: false}
              - {label: "Call to Action Link", name: "link", widget: "string", required: false, hint: "Call to Action Link"}
              - {label: "Call to Action Text", name: "buttontext", widget: "string", required: false, hint: "Call to Action Text"}
          - label: "Services"
            name: "services"
            widget: object
            fields:
              - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
              - {label: "Content", name: "content", widget: "markdown", required: false}
```

gatsby-node.js

```
exports.createPages = ({actions, graphql}) => {
  const {createPage} = actions;

  const pageTemplate = path.resolve('src/templates/page.js');
  return graphql(`{
    allMarkdownRemark {
      edges {
        node {

          id
          frontmatter {
            title
            path
            sections {
              buttontext
              content
              link
              title
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }`)
  .then(result => {
    if (result.errors) {
      result.errors.forEach(e => console.error(e.toString()))
      return Promise.reject(result.errors)
    }

    result.data.allMarkdownRemark.edges.forEach(({node}) => {
      createPage({
        path: node.frontmatter.path,
        component: pageTemplate,
        context: {
          id: node.id,
        }
      })
    })
  })
}
```

pagetemplate.js

```
import Helmet from 'react-helmet'
import Layout from "../components/layout"
//import CTA from '../components/sections/CTA-section'

export default function Template({ data }) {
  const {markdownRemark: page} = data

return (
  <Layout>
    <h1>{page.frontmatter.title}</h1>
    <p>{page.frontmatter.sections.title}</p>
    // <CTA />
  </Layout> 
)
}

export const pageQuery = graphql`
  query pageByPath($id: String!) {
    markdownRemark(id: { eq: $id } ) {
      id
      frontmatter {
        path
        title
        sections {
          title
          buttontext
          content
          link
        }
      }
    }
  }
`
```

GraphiQL screenshot
[graphiql screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rDLcd.png)

Bonus question: I also need to figure out how to make the component for these widgets. As you can see from the commented out lines in pagetemplate.js I would like to make separate components for each widget. Since the data is dynamic, I dont think I will be able to use StaticQuery, and I cant make another page query on the same data since it will be imported.

Comment: What exactly do you mean "can't pull the data from the widget"? Was is "the widget"? What is the problem? Without this information we cannot give an helpful answer. Please edit your question.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant my markdown file is shown. the "widgets" are the page sections identified in the md file ("Call To Action" and "Services" . When I try to access the data from my graphql query with "page.frontmatter.sections.title" no data is displayed. Not sure how I can better explain the question.